# Suppress TF_REPEATED_DATA warnings?

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've read [the discussions on why this warning is being printed](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467) but that's not really relevant to me. I'm trying to play back an old rosbag which published a TF repeatedly with the same timestamp. I only need the TF once so I don't care that the rest of the messages are ignored but I keep getting the message

`Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame...`

spamming my terminal making debugging other parts of my code impossible. So my question is how can I stop this message? I've tried changing the logging levels but loading a custom rosconsole file but there was no change. Here is the file I make:

```
#
#   rosconsole will find this file by default at $ROS_ROOT/config/rosconsole.config
#
#   You can define your own by e.g. copying this file and setting
#   ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE (in your environment) to point to the new file
# log4j.logger.ros=ERROR log4j.logger.ros.roscpp.superdebug=ERROR
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381529/suppress-tf_repeated_data-warnings?/) by [raabuchanan](https://answers.ros.org/users/76964/raabuchanan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run a version of geometry2 that reduces the warning by cloning this repo and branch in your catkin_ws/src:

```
git clone --branch throttle-tf-repeated-data-error git@github.com:BadgerTechnologies/geometry2.git
```

Then rebuild, source setup.bash, run and then it should be reduced down to once every 10 seconds.  If 10 seconds is still too much log output then change the `ros::Duration(10.0)` to 10000 seconds or whatever you like.

https://github.com/ros/geometry2/pull/516/files

I haven't actually run that branch but it looks reasonable that it will work as claimed.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2021-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on 2022-05-31**:
I can confirm that this works.

**Comment by [raabuchanan](https://answers.ros.org/users/76964/raabuchanan/) on 2023-02-08**:
Thank you! This worked like a charm. Ideally there would be a way to set the time delay without having to re-compile but for now this is great.

**Comment by [Muhammad_Usman](https://answers.ros.org/users/163111/muhammad_usman/) on 2023-07-17**:
this works

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone interested in a horribly over-engineered solution for suppressing TF_REPEATED_DATA warnings on the receiving end, I wrote the below Python code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import pipes
import threading
import sys

import rospy

class suppress_TF_REPEATED_DATA(object):
    r'''Standard error filter used to suppress TF_REPEATED_DATA warning messages.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        r'''Create a new warning suppressor object.
        '''
        self.__registered = False

    def __call__(self):
        r'''Replace the normal STDERR with a filter that suppresses
            `Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA` messages.
        '''
        if self.__registered:
            return

        # Because the filter works by redirecting STDERR to a pipe, it's not possible to
        # then print error messages that are not meant to be suppressed. The solution is
        # to create a child process to print those messages in place of this process.
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        def printer(queue):
            while True:
                line = queue.get()
                if line is None:
                    return

                sys.stderr.write(line)

        # Start the output process.
        self.__printer = multiprocessing.Process(target=printer, args=(queue,))
        self.__printer.start()

        # Preserve the normal STDERR.
        stderr_fileno = os.dup(2)
        stderr = sys.stderr

        # Create a pipe object and replace STDERR with it.
        piper = pipes.Template()
        pipe_name = rospy.get_name().replace('/', '_')
        pipe_out = piper.open(pipe_name, 'w')
        os.dup2(pipe_out.fileno(), 2)
        sys.stderr = pipe_out

        def read_pipe():
            skip = False

            # Open the pipe in read mode and read messages from it.
            with open(pipe_name) as pipe_in:
                while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                    line = pipe_in.readline()
                    if line.strip() == '':
                        continue

                    # The warning message is two lines long, so we need to also skip the line
                    # following the one starting with "Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA".
                    if skip:
                        skip = False
                        continue

                    if line.startswith('Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA'):
                        skip = True
                        continue

                    # If the line is not to be suppressed,
                    # send it to the child process for printing.
                    queue.put(line)

            # Stop the output process.
            queue.put(None)
            self.__printer.join()

            # Restore the normal STDERR.
            pipe_out.close()
            os.dup2(stderr_fileno, 2)
            sys.stderr = stderr

            self.__registered = False

        self.__reader = threading.Thread(target=read_pipe)
        self.__reader.start()

        self.__registered = True


# Turn the class into a singleton.
suppress_TF_REPEATED_DATA = suppress_TF_REPEATED_DATA()
```

Add this code to a module in your system, then import and call `suppress_TF_REPEATED_DATA()` right after the call to `rospy.init_node()`.

The implementation of a C++ solution is left as an exercise to the reader. ;)

---

Originally posted by [xperroni](https://answers.ros.org/users/26539/xperroni/) with karma: 11 on 2022-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1